# Last callback always active

Tags: javascript, node.js

`readfileSync` callback always work, even through no error and right status code. I want callback `readfileSync` only on error or timeout. In case if I remove else, all would work. I passing callback to another function, and in case there no connection or timeout I want fallback to local file.

```
  request({
    url: url,
    timeout: 800,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        cb(JSON.stringify(body));
    } else {
        cb(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8'));
    }
});
```

Comment: "even through no error and right status code" --- how do you know that?

Comment: If I remove else I could get right json from url. But with else, I always getting json from the local file.

Comment: "If I remove else" --- this says nothing about the actual values of `error` and `response.statusCode`. If you ever claim "even through no error and right status code" make sure you can provide the exact values for both.

Comment: I checked in the wireshark, more above if i had another code, I shouldn't see the right json from the url. I tried else if err with empty else also. Last callback always sets for some reason.

Comment: Provide the exact values for those.

Comment: Same result with:

`request({
    url: url,
    timeout: 800,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        cb(JSON.stringify(body));
    } else if (error) {
        cb(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8'));
    } else {}
});`

Comment: Your `err` is not what you think it is. Not sure why you think guessing is better than checking, but it looks like there is no way you provide the values for those variables.

Comment: @zerkms So you think I should remove statusCode?

Comment: I don't think one must randomly remove pieces of code and hope it fixes anything. My idea is that you should check the exact values of those variables. That's what I mentioned 4 times here already. But instead of doing that you continue speculating and guessing.

Comment: removed statusCode - no change. local file loads.

Comment: Local file still loads first
`if (error) {
            cb(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8'));
        } else {
            cb(JSON.stringify(body));
        }`

Comment: Right, so apparently you think that guessing is better than checking. Have fun, I'm out ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Increasing timeout helped. ESOCKETTIMEDOUT was hard to detect as it was quite random.